# Comparing unclassified super-objects with classified sub-objects

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, feature-class, land-cover, ecognition

I have two shapefiles exported from ecognition. The first shapefile contains the land cover classification and the second one contains unclassified superobjects of the first shapefile. I want to compute the percentage of each landcover classes within my superobjects. I also want to get the NDVI percentage of the superobjects based on the vegetation class.

I found this link http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000044000000
but I can't seem to find this in ArcMap. I don't know if I can use this to achieve what I want.

Comment: To use the Tabulate Intersection tool you have to have an Advanced license.  If you have that license it is located under the Analysis toolbox in the Statistics toolset.  If you do not have this license You can calculate the area of the superobjects into a double field and use the Union tool.  Then calculate the union_area/original_area * 100.  Either way should work for the first analysis you want to do.  See this link for NDVI preparation.  http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_the_percentage_of_green_spaces_in_remote_sensing_image_using_erdas_imagine

Comment: thanks a lot. unfortunately we don't have that license. hope i could do the other options right. thanks

Comment: If memory serves, tabulate areas in spatial analyst works on 2 polygon layers. Alternatively just use intersect tool and pivot table in Excel.

Comment: @RichardFairhurst I think your comment would make a brief answer.

Answer (score 1):

To use the Tabulate Intersection tool you have to have an Advanced license. If you have that license it is located under the Analysis toolbox in the Statistics toolset. If you do not have this license You can calculate the area of the superobjects into a double field and use the Union tool. Then calculate the union_area/original_area * 100. Either way should work for the first analysis you want to do. See this link for NDVI preparation. https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_the_percentage_of_green_spaces_in_remote_sensing_image_using_erdas_imagine